# Do Metal device pointers persist across dispatches?

Tags: ios, macos, gpgpu, metal

Say I dispatch threads to run a compute kernel, passing them an `MTLBuffer`. Then, on the Metal side, I generate `device` pointers to data in that buffer, and store them in another buffer.

If I dispatch another set of threads, running a different kernel, are said pointers guaranteed to still be valid?

A source would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no, but why would you ever need them to be? Just pass the same `MTLBuffer` again...? Maybe try explaining what you're trying to achieve - maybe there's another way.

Comment: @Itai do you have a source? I can't share details of the code as it's confidential, but storing pointers is common practice and IMO has obvious utility. :)

Comment: I think on tier 2 argument buffer hardware `device` pointers should persist if the `MTLBuffer` object remains alive on CPU side of things.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy interesting, have you got a source reference on that?